# How can I hook up my Ruby script to my database using a database.yml file?

Tags: sql-server, ruby, database, tiny-tds

I'm wanting to use my database with a ruby script that I've created.  Right now I'm writing the database connector into the model file I've created like so...

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name_prefix = "MyDatabase."

  establish_connection(
    :adapter => "sqlserver",
    :host => "XXXX",
    :port => "14XX",
    :database => "XXXX",
    :username => "XXXX",
    :password => "XXXX"
  )

end
```

But since I'm trying to check in my project to Github I wanted to pull the credentials and connection info out into a `database.yml` file that I could add to my `.gitignore`. I never really looked into how this worked with a Rails project, but would like to mimic it for this Ruby script.

Comment: Read the YML file and use that while establishing the connection. BTW, it is a bad practice to make connection within your model

Comment: Establish connection with ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection from outside the model.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I've pieced together to work... not sure this is the best way but it allows me to .gitignore the database.yml and keep important credentials out of my github project.

**main.rb**

```
require 'active_record'
require 'tiny_tds'
require './config/initializers/initializer.rb'
```

**config/initializers/initializer.rb**

```
@dbconfig = YAML.load(File.read("./config/database.yml"))
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(@dbconfig)

Dir["./models/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
```

**database.yml**

```
adapter: sqlserver
username: XXXX
password: XXXX
host: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
port: 1433
database: "mydatabasename"
pool: 5
timeout: 15000
```